# CakePHP Count syntax

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am writing an app in CakePHP and need to get a count of posts for an image. its a one (image) to many (comments) link.

I have tried the following but it doesnt work as it cant find the table? I know I have managed to do this with just SQL queries in previous applications.

This is the code

```
$data = $this->Image->find('all', array(
'fields' => array('COUNT(Comment.comment_id) AS total', 'Image.*'),
'group' => array('Image.logo_id')
));
```

basically I want to output the image details and then a comment count which is associated to the image.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting debug level to 2 in the config file and see what happens. CakePHP should stop caching the structure of your database.

Comment: Have you looked at [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count)?

Comment: @Mike I have been able to do it the other way around as in count from the Comment table. Debug is set to L2, but it says it cant find the table Comment.

Comment: @deizel, yes I have seen that, but didnt think it was a brilliant solution...

Comment: How so? It's built specifically for this purpose. Admittedly it can't handle complex joins, but this is quite a simple requirement and should solve your problem nicely.

Comment: Actually I take it back, its perfect, if only i read the documentation a bit more :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) seems to be the answer, thanks guys!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so that this question doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list.